# Getting following error in sqlloader

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

> SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (C:\sqlloaderpra\tmp.txt)
>   SQL*Loader-553: file not found SQL*Loader-509: System error: The
>   system cannot find the file specified. SQL*Loader-2026: the load was
>   aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.

Where my ctrl file is

```
load data
infile 'C:\sqlloaderpra\tmp.txt'
into table tmpload
append
fields terminated by ","
trailing nullcols
(
a Integer external,
b char nullif b=blanks)
```

Files are there but i get this error.

Comment: Did you try move the file to another location?

Comment: Maybe to `D:\sqlloaderpra\` ?

Comment: Maybe you have problem with privileges.

Comment: No i have only one drive in it.couldnt find y this causing

Comment: do this in a DOS window. `dir /q C:\sqlloaderpra\*txt` does it show you the file, and if so, is the owner your own login?

Comment: When i view this i got tmp.txt.txt .I modified to tmp.txt..Its working.
Thank you so much DazzaL